# Calling default handler from a custom authentication handler

Tags: symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symfony2 AJAX Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607212/symfony2-ajax-login)

I have implemented a custom authentication handler service to handle AJAX login requests, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312188/267705

But **how can I handle normal login requests?** It would be nice to call the default behavior, but I don't know and haven't found how to do it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *handle*?

Comment: Look at the link in the question, I mean the void else statements.

Comment: Well, I wrote the answer you are linking to. ;) What I don't understand is what you mean by the word *handle*. What is your use case without technical details?

Comment: Oh ok :) I want to handle Ajax login and normal login. So I implemented your authentication handler. Ajax works fine, but normal login does not, as it falls in the else, so I have to return something. I would like to return to the login page showing the errors, or redirecting after a successful login, as the default behavior. But with your authentication handler I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the ways to achieve what you want:

```php
namespace YourVendor\UserBundle\Handler;

// "use" statements here

class AuthenticationHandler
implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,
           AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            // Handle XHR here
        } else {
            // If the user tried to access a protected resource and was forces to login
            // redirect him back to that resource
            if ($targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.target_path')) {
                $url = $targetPath;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, redirect him to wherever you want
                $url = $this->router->generate('user_view', array(
                    'nickname' => $token->getUser()->getNickname()
                ));
            }

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            // Handle XHR here
        } else {
            // Create a flash message with the authentication error message
            $request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());
            $url = $this->router->generate('user_login');

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy. ;)

Comment: I have an error when I generate the 'user_login' route on authentication failure. Whatever I try (login, login_path, user_login), the route fails to be generated and I have a "Route does not exist" error.
Where is this route being configured? How may I modify it in order for it to be generated?

Comment: @GabrielTheron, it's just a usual route you define for usual actions. Read the [section on traditinal login forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm using FOSUserBundle, and I think it overrides this route to use 'fos_user_security_login' instead. It is the only path that worked for me.