# Custom AuthenticationHandler not implementing interface correctly - why?

Tags: symfony

This question relates to

[How to disable redirection after login_check in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308050/how-to-disable-redirection-after-login-check-in-symfony-2)

I have implemented the solution given at that link exactly but am receiving an error I usually understand but on this occasion do not. My class absolutely implements the interface perfectly (I think).

Fatal error: Declaration of     Foo\AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler::onAuthenticationSuccess() must be compatible with    that of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface::onAuthenticationSuccess() in /Users/Me/Sites/github/Foo/Symfony/src/Foo/AppBundle/Handler/AuthenticationHandler.php on line 6

```
class AuthenticationHandler implements
\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,
\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
        return new Response();
    }

    function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP thinks that `Request`, `TokenInterface` are from the current namespace but the interfaces' declaration requires them to be from `Symfony\*` namespace.
Try to add using statements or use FQN for these classes:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
```

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that :) Thank so much

Comment: Thanks you so much :)