# Symfony2 customize the authentication method

Tags: authentication, symfony

How can I add logic to Symfony2's authentication method?

for example, blocking one's login attempts after certain amount of failed logins.

Comment: Are you using the FOSUserBundle???

Comment: nope, I use my own user bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in an authentication handler. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308050/how-to-disable-redirection-after-login-check-in-symfony-2/8312188#8312188) of an authentication handler which you can adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should define service that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface` and in method `onAuthenticationFailure()` you can increase attribute which handle number of attempts. If number reach limit you just switch user attribute `enabled` to `false`

Comment: there's no way for altering the authentication method itself?