# How to go back to referer after login failure?

Tags: redirect, symfony, authentication, referer

For login success there is a parameter `use_referer: true`. For login failure there is only `failure_path`, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Second thing: How to do that and pass error message?

Third thing: How to go back to referrer after logout?

Comment: why wouldn't the failure path just be the login prompt?

Comment: because I can login from every subpage. I haven't got one login form on specified url, so I don't want to redirect user to homepage when he's login from for example another user profile page.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I solved it.

There is solution: [How to disable redirection after login_check in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308050/how-to-disable-redirection-after-login-check-in-symfony-2/8312188#8312188)

and here is code which solves my problem:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface, LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {       
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');       
        $request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());

        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) 
    {
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }
}
```

to handle events add to security.yml for example:

```
form_login:
    check_path: /access/login_check
    login_path: /
    use_referer: true
    failure_handler: authentication_handler  
logout:
    path:   /access/logout
    target: /
    success_handler: authentication_handler
```

and to config.yml:

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Acme\MainBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
```

Comment: $request->headers->get('referer'); sometimes returns null (I've reproduced in Firefox). This solution is not reliable, a fallback or another solution is necessary.

Comment: @wojciech-kulik I have the following error: 
```$request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());```
```FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session::setFlash() in /var/www/symfony/src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Form/Handler/AuthenticationHandler.php line 16```

Comment: @webyseo Probably you've got a different version of Symphony and flash messages are set in a different way.
Maybe it will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348534/symfony-2-setting-a-flash-message-outside-of-controller

Comment: @WojciechKulik Exactly solved with ```$session->getFlashBag()->add('error', $exception->getMessage());``` thanks!!

Comment: How to get doctrine in onAuthenticationFailure function for login throttling. $user->setLocked(true);

Comment: how to use doctrine inside onAuthenticationFailure function.?

Comment: @Ramesh ask this in your own question ;)