# Symfony2: Set flash message after UNsuccessful login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUSerBundle and have successfully overwritten Controllers, Forms and Views.

But I cannot find the correct place to set a flash message after unsuccessful login.

I already tried modifying the checkAction() in SecurityController.php, but it doesnt work.

Where is the correct place to set my flash message?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312188/453348)

Comment: thanks, tttony for the link. i suppose it does what i need, but after trying it out i came to the conclusion, that this approach is way to complicated for what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem pretty straight-forward:

1.) have overwritten the SecurityController and edited the loginAction

2.) hooked into the case where the login process returns an not empty $error

```
// in case the login process returns an error...
if ($error) {
    $error = $error->getMessage();

    // ... add the desired flash message to display
    $session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'my error message here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to overwrite the controller for it.

I overwrite the login.html.twig file and give the user the errors with the following line:

```
{% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
 {% endif %}
```