# Treatment Routes of hwi_oauth in symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, hwioauthbundle

I have a project where I log in with the auth and from time to time it's an error and it is not possible to connect. And I would have something to show me this error, so I can do the treatment and return a message to the User.

When he does not connect it automaiticamente back to the root, and that this ta treaty on security:

```
oauth:
    resource_owners:
        facebook:   "/security/login/check-facebook"
        google:     "/security/login/check-google"
        linkedin:   "/security/login/check-linkedin"
    login_path: /
    failure_path: /
    default_target_path: /security/connected
    check_path: /security/login_check
    oauth_user_provider:
        service: web_key_user_provider
```

Mainly to get treatment when the authentication page facebook or google me return one bad_request = 400

as I would for the Routa to put in `failure_path`, to catch because it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement an `EventListener` which is called when the `onAuthenticationFailure` event is fired, and set it as `failure_handler` in your HWIOAuth configuration.

See this great answer on another similar issue :

[How to disable redirection after login_check in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308050/how-to-disable-redirection-after-login-check-in-symfony-2/8312188#8312188)

Hopes this helps you.