# Global Route on condition

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a tutorial page, and need a global redirect 
that will send to user to `/tutoroal` if they don't pass a DB check: 
`User->passedTutorial()`

Can I make this with a route configuration calling a controller/model method ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like a security context/question. Have you considered creating a custom role, eg `ROLE_USER_PASSED`?

You could then either check for this role in security.yml or annotate your controllers with `@Security("has_role('ROLE_USER_PASSED')")`

Comment: That sounds good, I checked that option, but is there a way to make a redirect if the check fails ?

Comment: Yes, a quick search shows that an authentication handler should be able to do this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308050/how-to-disable-redirection-after-login-check-in-symfony-2))

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using @Security annotation like described there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html.

Particularly:

```
/**
 * @Security("user.passedTutorial()")
 */
```

**UPD.**

Finally problem can be solved using expression in **access_control** section of security.yml: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression

By doing so it's still needed to implement **access_denied_handler** in used firewall (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) so that it will check the request/user again and perform redirect.

Comment: this will just restrict the access to a single controller, I need a way to redirect from any controller, to a single page (if the check fails)

Comment: Got it. Then you can still use expression like describe there http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression.

Comment: this lokks great @Dmitry, I will try it next week.
If you can edit your answer and add a working exmple, I will be happy to accept it